# Change pivot or local origin of an object

Tags: transforms

How can I change the local origin of an object, without changing the object location in the world space.

This is the object located at position (0,0,0) in the world space

[image]

This is the same object located at position (0,1,0) in the world space, but with its local origin offset so that the object is in the same place

[image]

**Is there a way to do this in a single step?**

Answer (score 275, accepted):

One way to do this is by entering *Edit* mode and placing the *3D cursor* where you want the new origin. *(When doing this, you can be very precise by selecting vertices, edges or faces and using them as guides. If you pick several points and snap the cursor to them using* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> → *Cursor to Selected*, *Blender will use the average of the selected points to determine the new location of the cursor)*.

[image]

You then go back to *Object* mode and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> → *Origin to 3D Cursor* to update or change the object origin to the location of the *3D cursor*.

For 2.9+ you need to go to *Object Menu*, and select *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*.

[image]

Comment: With all the attention this has gotten, this seems to be a good idea, https://rightclickselect.com/p/modeling/vqbbbc/interactive-pivot. Maybe someone with a little time on their hands could tackle it. :)

Comment: For properly center object from blender for unity I was needed to place 3D cursor to the zero coordinates (0, 0, 0) and then place the center of mesh object using Origin to 3D Cursor.

Comment: My pivot point has become rotated, how do I restore the rotation to be non rotated with respect to the rotation in world coordinates?

Comment: @rien333 Best to ask a new question, not sure what you mean by *"pivot point has become rotated"*.

Comment: Okay, I will. Its pretty obscure, some old threads show up on Google but people in general just act confused.

Comment: Here is the question if anyone is interested (I guess it also pretty related to this one):
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77224/change-object-pivot-point-orientation

Comment: When you want to check your modification in Unity, make sure you toggle the button to "Pivot" in Unity Editor to see where the new pivot point is. Otherwise, you would still see the center of the gameObject.

Comment: I would like to upvote your answer every time I need this. +4 till now.

Comment: [`Ctrl + Alt + Shift + C` doesn't work since 2.8](https://www.katsbits.com/codex/origin/); choose it from the menu (no shortcut). Another option is to move the origin directly as mentioned in Robert's answer.

Answer (score 42):

This is useful to have as a script, I wrote one back in 2011. It uses the 3d cursor but restores its original position.

A link to this script is [`here`](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5844379) (includes all addon boilerplate) Once installed the script can be run from `3d view` > `space bar` > `Origin Move to Selected`

This is the juicy bit:

```
def execute(self, context):
    saved_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location.copy()
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')  
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = saved_location

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

To bind this to a key combo:

- `User Preferences` >  `Input` > `3D View` > `3D View (Global)` > `New`.
- Then fill in the text field with `object.origin_to_selected` and Blender will name the short-cut correctly. Then pick your short-cut keys: 
  [image]

More work up front, but convenient when used hourly.

Comment: Very handy! I knew it could be done with scripting, but I'm new on that topic

Comment: Very nice.. This should be part of Blender distribution.

Comment: How can be added undo support?

Comment: hmm, this might take a bit longer, i will let you know when I find time to add undo. it's not just a simple `bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}`

Comment: @rraallvv, i recoded it to manipulate directly the verts and object location, https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5879583,  but still no nice undo.. :/ maybe someone else has a solution. I realize I've never used undo for something like this:)

Comment: @rraallvv the best way I know at the moment is, and this only works immediately after the origin switch..  is to go to object mode and hit undo.

Comment: 2.8 update is here: https://gist.github.com/vansoest/db2a34f3bd80547060517baecfc531b7

Answer (score 34):

In Blender 2.81 the transform tools can be restricted to only affect the origins, which allows to translate it directly.

1. Open the *Options* in the *Tool Settings*
2. In the *Transform - Affect Only* section check *Origins*
3. Select an object and adjust the origin using the shortcut <kbd>G</kbd> to move it. Alternatively you can also use the *Move* tool from the toolbar for the interactive gizmo.

[image: Enable transform only for the origins]
[image: Moving the origin by using the move tool]

Comment: In addition to the above, I also use the "Snap to" tool and set it to "Edge" and "Closest" so that I get exact positioning of the origin to be at the very edge of the object (which is usually what most folks want when they move the origin).

Answer (score -1):

In Object Mode, first select the Object you want to change the Origin.
Then click *Manipulate Center points* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>) It is the 3rd button on the right from the *Object mode* in the 3D header.
Switch to Edit Mode, if your Object is not selected, press <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> twice to select everything.
Move the selected object with the 3D manipulator. It works now relative to the center point.
When you are done, go back to Object Mode and uncheck *Manipulate Center points* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>).

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong. The "manipulate center points" button only works with rotation, in "object" or "pose" modes. To move the pivot point of an object, this option is useless... However, manipulating the whole vertices of an object in "edit" mode will do the trick, as you said.