# How to toggle between Flat and Smooth shading during animation?

Tags: animation, mesh, properties

The *Edge Split* modifier doesn't give me desired results (even with angle set to 0 it looks different).

Comment: What do you mean it looks different? Can you post a screenshot comparing the two? There isn't a way to insert keyframes for Smooth/Flat shading, so edge split is your only choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Animatable (custom property) toggle

```
import bpy

def toggle_shading(self, context=bpy.context):
    """Toggle smooth shading"""
    value = self["use_smooth"]
    if self.polygons[0].use_smooth is not value:
        for poly in self.polygons:
            poly.use_smooth = value

def frame_handler(scene):
    """Update shading on frame change"""
    for mesh in bpy.data.objects.data.meshes:
        try:
            toggle_shading(mesh)
        except KeyError:
            pass

bpy.types.Mesh.use_smooth = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    description=toggle_shading.__doc__, update=toggle_shading)
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler)
```

1. Paste the script above in the [Text Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Text_editor), click <kbd>Register</kbd> and <kbd>Run Script</kbd>.

   - Text block name must end with ".py" to activate the register functionality (run script on load).
2. In the Properties Window, under Object Data, <kbd>Add</kbd> a custom property with *Property Name* `use_smooth` and *Property Value* of `0`.

   - You can now animate this value the toggle smooth shading.

[image: Added property]

Comment: Thank you, guys! The second one seems to better suits my needs. But I can't force it to work. http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/5430/cjzv.jpg

Comment: @Sielan, You added the property to _Object_ not _Object Data_.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now it works! :) BTW. Is there a way to run this script automatically each time when I load the scene?

Comment: @Sielan, that's what the _Register_ check-box does. This feature requires the name of the text block to end with ".py".

Comment: @Sielan [feel free to accept this as the answer that worked when you are ready.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object#comment2202_1291)

Answer (score 8):

## I still think that edge split is the way to go:

- Make sure edge split is the last modifier.
- Make sure that it is smooth shaded without it.
- Set edge split angle to zero and check the angle.
- Add desired keyframes for the angle checkbox.

## Frame One:

[image: Frame One]

## Frame Six:

[image: Frame Six]

Answer (score 4):

Let me preface this with saying that this method won't let you set key-frames with the UI, [Aldrik's approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1694/47) does.

My method lends itself better to a procedural approach to animation where key-framing isn't important. This script accepts a list of `start-end` ranges, which map to the frame numbers that should be shaded flat or smooth.

- Hit run on this script, then start the animation render

script:

```
import bpy

def list_to_frames(ranges):
    k = set()
    for begin, finish in ranges:
        k = k | {i for i in range(begin, finish)}
    return k

def my_handler(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current

    obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]

    # this assumes you are OK with doing a full sweep
    # and setting all to either smooth or flat.
    if not frame in frames:
        if obj.data.polygons[0].use_smooth == True:
            return
        for poly in obj.data.polygons:
            poly.use_smooth = True
    else:
        if obj.data.polygons[0].use_smooth == False:
            return
        for poly in obj.data.polygons:
            poly.use_smooth = False

frames_to_flatshade = [[20,30],[45,54]]
obj_name = 'Cube'
frames = list_to_frames(frames_to_flatshade)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

Here's a [compacted version of this script](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5945040)