# Setting the pivot point of an object

Tags: objects

I have a sword that currently rotates around a pivot point thats off of the actual object. Im new to blender and im not sure how i would go about changing it so that the sword rotates around the handle. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1291/599

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to either change the `origin` of the object, or use the 3D Cursor as a pivot point.

A quick way to change what is used as a pivot point, is to look at the bottom menu in the 3d view and select "Pivot center for rotation/scaling":

[image]

But to actually change the object's origin, you could first move the 3D Cursor to whereever you want the pivot point. To do this accurately, you can snap it to whatever you have selected (both in `Object Mode` and `Edit Mode` by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and choosing "Cursor to selected".

[image: S]
[image]

Then, in `Object Mode` with you object selected, use the Object Tools menu on the left (<kbd>T</kbd> to make the menu appear if you don't see it), press `Origin` button, and choose "Origin to 3D Cursor".

[image]-->[image]
[image]

**For Blender 2.8:**

The ['Pivot Point' selector](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html?highlight=pivot%20point) can be found at the top of your viewport in a drop-down with a double 'chain-link' icon on it

[image: Option drop-down]

Comment: Although, if your pivot point is far off the object itself, "cursor to selected" will place the cursor... Outside the object! Placing the pivot point back inside the object is sometimes hard

Comment: That helped me, but I actually had to select the object in Object Mode, go in Edit Mode, snap Cursor to Selected, then go back to Object Mode, then Origin to 3D Cursor. Doing in Object Mode only wouldn't allow me to snap (working with Curves here).