# Animate object on arc trajectory

Tags: animation

How can I animate object rotating with center of rotation offsetted?

I want to animate hammer making movements like someone is using it.

Comment: Set the cursor where you want the pivot point, set origin to cursor then you should be able to rotate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5521/1853 Change the origin of the object where you need it and rotate the object using the new pivot point.

[image]

To animate, go the frame where you want the animation to start and press <kbd>I</kbd> to create a key frame for the rotation. Move then to a different frame, rotate your object and press <kbd>I</kbd> to create a new key frame.

[image]

To swing the hammer in an arc motion change the origin further away from the handle.

[image]

Comment: that would work perfectly for the part of the movement where the hammer goes down, but on the way up it's a bit more complicated trajectory. I think that can be accomplished by using curves (I'm guessing, I don't realy know)

Comment: Should it be noted that a hammer moves more like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/81682)?