# How can I animate an edge loop?

Tags: animation, edges

I have a simple gauge that I want to animate to make the green part fill the gauge progressively.

[image]

[image]

The whole gauge is also slowly rotating on its Y axis while this is happening.

I tried looking online for help, but couldn't find any.
I also looked for a long time in several places such as the Object panel to try and find the coordinates of this edge loop, but didn't find them.

I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: You may do it using shapekeys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may do this using ***Shape Keys***.
[image]

Being in *Object Mode* go to the *Data* header and in a ***Shape Keys*** panel add a key (press the ***'+'*** button) and name it *location*. Enable the ***apply shapekeys in edit mode*** option. Now enter the *Edit Mode*, change the *location* key value to ***1*** and slide your edge loop along the object. Next set the *location* key value back to ***0***.
[image]

Go to frame *1* on your *timeline*, hover your cursor over the *Value* slider in a *Shape Keys* panel and press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe.
[image]

Go to the next desired frame on your *timeline*, change the shapekey *Value* to *1* and press <kbd>I</kbd> again.
[image]

Now insert the keyframe for rotation. Being in *Object Mode*, in *3D window* go to frame *1* and press <kbd>I</kbd>-->*LocRotScale* (or just *Rotation*).
[image]

Go to the next desired frame on your *timeline*, rotate your object (<kbd>R</kbd>) and press <kbd>I</kbd>-->*LocRotScale* again.
[image]

If you want a constant movement of your animation go to the ***Graph Editor***, press <kbd>T</kbd> and change the *keyframe interpolation type* to ***Linear***.
[image]

Remember, that you can change the duration of inserted keyframes animation. Go to the ***Dope Sheet Editor***, select the desired action and place it (using <kbd>G</kbd>) wherever you like on a timeline. In my case I've increased the green gauge speed.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! My "+" button in the Shape Keys data panel is greyed out, both when the object is selected and isn't, you know why that could be?

Comment: That's because you are in the Edit Mode. You can add new shapekeys (usng '+' button) being in Object Mode only.

Comment: Wait, so I have to apply them in Object mode but then I have to go back to Edit mode to modify the object right? When I rotate the shape then play the animation, it shrinks towards the middle and then becomes the normal site again, is this normal? http://ge.tt/5Rh6gSQ2/v/0 oh and also when I press i (it's a i, right? looks like a L) I get "active shape key index" property cannot be animated

Comment: You add new shapekeys in Object Mode and edit them in Edit Mode. Probably your mesh shrinks, because the origin point isn't inside it. Place the origin point in the center of your object and apply the loc, rot and scale (Ctrl+A in Object Mode) and then edit the shapekeys. About the "active shape key index property cannot be animated'' problem- to keyframe the shapekey value (by pressing 'I'- like Independence) you need to place your cursor over the value, not the keyframe name (the name cannot be keyframed but the value can). Btw, the link you posted is broken.

Comment: Sorry about the link being broken. I followed this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/setting-the-pivot-point-of-an-object
But the shape still shrinks when I apply the rotation. Here's the screen grab I was trying to share earlier; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f86ZHLwqmnM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @fabrice d I now know why this rotating issue appears. I forgot that shape keys are not good for animating rotation like this (cause the keyed vertices change their position moving linear). You should use a 'standard' keyframe insertion for rotation. I've rebuilded my answer. Now it should work fine for you :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm just getting back to this, and I can't find the way to change the value of the location shape key: http://i.imgur.com/Vo8PNZy.png hope you can help, sorry I wasn't working on this for a while

Comment: Oh that was the Basis one. Thanks a lot! Solved it. Great!