# How to use multiple shape keys to modify the same value(like rotation on x-axis) but in multiple ways?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, vertex-groups

*I have been trying to find a way to use multiple shape keys to modify the same value(like rotation on x-axis) but in multiple ways to make my workflow better as I can already use hook object for that so if any of you know of a way please answer it will be a better way for me to set up animations than the **clumsy** hook objects.*

> And I would like to mention it works fine for scaling but in case of
>   rotation there are some problems.

See:[image]

Comment: Shape keys are displacing the vertices in a straight line, it is not a good idea using them for rotation.

Comment: I agree with Denis. It's not a good idea to use *shape keys* for animating rotation like this, because the vertices change their position in a linear way. You should just keyframe a rotation (**I-->Rotation**) instead. A bit related answer, which may be helpful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40304/how-can-i-animate-an-edge-loop