# How to set mesh center in Edit Mode?

Tags: mesh, objects, workflow, transforms, edit-mode

I know how to set the center to the *3D Cursor* in *Object Mode* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but when I go into *Edit Mode* and select all, the center is in a different place and therefore it rotates around the wrong point.

How do I change the *Pivot Point* in *Edit Mode* to be the same as in *Object Mode*?

Thanks

Comment: You can set the cursor to the center of the object and change the pivot point to the cursor.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/setting-the-pivot-point-of-an-object

Comment: thanks, i see that menu now, 2 to the right of the mode options