# Proportionally scaling a mesh

Tags: mesh, scale

I'm new to Blender, but I come from SketchUp. I would like to extend a stair a little bit to match other geometry, but I'm really struggling to get it done. The bottom of the stair is already fitted with snap tool. Now I would like to deform the top, so it matches the rest of the geometry. Is it possible?

[image: General view of the scene]

[image: What I want to achieve]

As I come from SketchUp, I'm used to use the scale tool and simply pull the geometry as I show down in a test I made to illustrate it (please, forgive it's done in SketchUp, but I need it just to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve as I can't do it in Blender).

[image: I can pull the object in the arrow direction]
[image: And deform the stairs]

As you can see in my example, all the steps are deformed, but they stay proportional. Can I do something similar with Blender or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I found the answer myself! Sorry people! It seems Pivot point is our friend! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/setting-the-pivot-point-of-an-object   Using it, we can change the pivot point used as the origin of the scale (or the rotation)

Comment: good to hear you solved it, feel free to add an answer detailing what you found, for other users with similar "issues"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: Pivot point! I discovered I can edit the pivoting point Blender uses to transform the geometry. So if I choose the opposite edge middle point as the Pivot point (marked by an orange dot), I can then change the scale of my stair with total control :)

More info here: [Setting the pivot point of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/setting-the-pivot-point-of-an-object)