# Removing a dot vertex at coordinate center of wrl import?

Tags: import

I'm trying to get a `.wrl` 3D circuit, exported from [kicad 3D rendering | SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kicad-3d/), into Blender, and I'm getting an element I cannot remove. Here is my procedure:

First, I'm using this `.wrl` (short version of `/usr/share/kicad/modules/packages3d/smd/generic_bga.wrl`) as my part model, which I call `bga.wrl`:

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8
#Exported from Wings 3D 0.98.34
DEF cube1_sep3 Transform {
  children [
    Shape {
      appearance Appearance {
        material DEF metal Material {
          diffuseColor 1.00000 1.00000 0.786667
          emissiveColor 0.00000e+0 0.00000e+0 0.00000e+0
          specularColor 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
          ambientIntensity 0.922222
          transparency 0.00000e+0
          shininess 1.00000
        }
      }
      geometry IndexedFaceSet {
        coord Coordinate { point [
          4.15121 -4.12469 6.77561e-3,
          4.15122 4.12652 6.77561e-3,
          -4.17102 -4.12467 6.76384e-3,
          -4.17101 4.12654 6.76384e-3,
          4.15121 -4.12469 0.225658,
          -4.24526 -4.12467 0.225643,
          4.15122 4.12652 0.225658,
          -4.24525 4.12654 0.225643,
          3.74080 -3.71428 0.326457,
          -3.83485 -3.71427 0.326446,
          3.74081 3.71612 0.326457,
          -3.83485 3.71613 0.326446 ] }
        coordIndex [
          0, 1, 6, 4, -1,
          0, 2, 3, 1, -1,
          0, 4, 5, 2, -1,
          1, 3, 7, 6, -1,
          2, 5, 7, 3, -1,
          4, 6, 10, 8, -1,
          4, 8, 9, 5, -1,
          5, 9, 11, 7, -1,
          6, 7, 11, 10, -1 ]
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Then, in the "3D rendering" `pcbnew` (board editing program of Kicad; I run it under `wine` on Ubuntu 11.04), I make a new part in the module editor, reusing the footprint (2D) of the resistor module `R4`, and assigning it's 3D model to be the above `bga.wrl`. Then I place two of these custom parts on an empty board at the left edge, one at top, one at bottom. I check if the 3D rendering works; and then I export a .wrl of the whole board (I've tried to include that file, which I called `_2r_bga_export.wrl`, 460kB in size, below).

Now, I try to import that file in Blender (deleting everything in the default file first); everything works fine, except:

[image: blender-_2r_bga_export.wrl]

... there is this "dot", which apparently refers to the top left corner of the PCB, appearing! (on the image, the 3D cursor can be placed on it by right-clicking)

It irritates the hell out of me, so I'd like to delete it; using TAB, I can go into edit mode, and with B I can box-select that vertex; however, after I delete it, it is *again* there! What's more, in that file, *only* `ShapeIndexedFaceSet.008` to `ShapeIndexedFaceSet.011` show that dot/vertex - but even if I delete those vertices from each affected shape individually, I *still* get the darn orange dot - except after that point, I cannot box-select any vertices at that location anymore?

So how do I delete that "PCB coordinate center" dot vertex?

---

EDIT: here is a minimal standalone `test.wrl` file, which demonstrates the same issue upon import in Blender (orange dot at coord. center, but this time unselectable):

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8
WorldInfo {
  title "Jaj"
}
Transform {
  # translation -1.175 5.725 0.0
  children [
Transform {
  children [
    Group {
      children [
        Shape {
          appearance Appearance {
            material Material {
              diffuseColor 0.831373 0.686275 0.215686
              specularColor 0.831373 0.686275 0.215686
              emissiveColor 0.831373 0.686275 0.215686
              ambientIntensity 0.8
              transparency 0.2
              shininess 0.2
            }
          }
          geometry IndexedFaceSet {
            solid TRUE
            coord Coordinate {
              point [
                # these are coordinates indexed 0, 1 and 2:
                1.16 -2.5 -3.15
                1.156926 -4.3121 -3.15
                1.156926 -4.3121 3.15
              ]
            }
            coordIndex [
              0 1 2 -1
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

---

PS: To get `_2r_bga_export.wrl`, save the below as `tmp.txt`, and then in a Linux shell (see also [ascii output of string compression in C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032810/ascii-output-of-string-compression-in-c)), do

```
cat tmp.txt | base64 -d | tar xJvf -
```

; that should unpack the file.

```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```

Comment: Can you share the blend file in question with the problem vertex.

Comment: Thanks @iKlsR - I just added a smaller example as an edit to OP; save the text of `test.wrl` above as a text file - and do `File > Import > X3D Extensible 3D (.x3d/.wrl)` and import this `test.wrl` file in Blender, you should be able to see the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "dot vertex" you cannot remove is the [**object origin**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/origin.htmls). I haven't tried the main file since I don't have access to the unix commands so I will try to explain the problem(s) using the test example.

First, the origin is quite off from the main model which is why it is possibly so irritating when transforming the model so you can try to snap or center it to the model with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. This will move the **object origin** slightly but won't work as desired as you actually have a loose vertex so the tool will try to average the center using the main mesh and this point, simply enter edit mode and delete it.

Next, run the *Set Origin* tool again and this time the origin will be snapped to the geometry. I think having the origin offset being unselectable and the duplicate vertex was what was confusing you. You can tell where the origin point is on an object by enabling the *3d manipulator widget*. [image]. If you don't want to see the origin, keep the widget disabled.

Also note, you cannot select or delete the **object origin** . It is fixed to your mesh and will move with it in *object mode*, to manipulate it use the tool I mentioned above along with the *3D cursor* (left click).

You might also want to see, [Change pivot or local origin of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object/1292) or spend a few minutes in the [transforms](/questions/tagged/transforms) tag.

Comment: Wow, fantastic, thanks so much @iKlsR - I started only late to suspect that the orange dot I see is maybe _not_ a vertex `:)` It works both for the minimal `test.wrl` - and with the "big" `_2r_bga_export.wrl`: in the big, I just select all ("A") in object mode, do Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C, in "Set Origin" choose "Origin to Center of Mass" - and that is exactly what I needed! Thanks for clarifying this - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

That's Blender's representation of the origin point. It represents the point around which transforms are applied. You cannot delete it.

Comment: Thanks for that @someonewithpc; indeed - and it turns out, what I wanted to do was not to delete, but to recenter the origin point. Cheers!