# Why is there a white dot in my scene?

Tags: blend-modes

I am trying to get rid of this white dot,[image] but can't seem to... does anyone know how to help?

Comment: Not quite the same but the answers there solve this. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15988/removing-a-dot-vertex-at-coordinate-center-of-wrl-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot displays the origin of your object. This also defines the axis the object will rotate on. It won't show up in your render though.