# Using the Screw modifier, how do I accurately set the axis of rotation?

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I got two good answers to my previous question about using a profile to create a mesh.  The problem I am still having is that I can't get the axis of rotation in the right place.  One thread said to position the 3D Cursor on the axis and another said to move the axis to the Origin.  I redid this three times. The last time was the closest. Still, the axis of rotation varied from ideal. How do I position the 3D cursor more accurately so as to make the axis of rotation where I want it to be? [image]

Comment: Select a vertex and press `Shift`+`S` *> Selection*, see if that helps

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object/

Comment: The screw modifier simply uses the object's origin as the point of rotation, [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1292/5705) shows how to reposition an object's origin.

Comment: Just wondering : are you talking about the screw modifier (that uses object axis and rotates around the object's origin) or the spin tool (wich is rotating around the 3D cursor using view axis)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modifier uses the objects (local) axis (X, Y, Z)

Modeling from top side or front ortho view will make things simple. use numpad<kbd>5</kbd> to switch orthogonal/perspective view

Shape modeled in top ortho view (green line is Y global axis)

[image]

Screw modifier set on Z object axis

[image]

Screw modifier set on Y object axis

[image]

Once modeled, you can move your object or rotate it (object mode) but in edit mode, you'll get a mess. Apply modifier or clear rotations for editing.

Comment: @ideasman42 Good point, thx for edit.