# How to Model a Mushroom shape?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Is there any good way to make a half decent mushroom?

I'm specifically trying to make the mushroom on the back of Parasect for an animation. How can you make a rounded cone? Is there an addon for that, or do I have to make it myself?

Specifically, I'm thinking of a cross between an ovoid three-dimensional shape and a cone.

(It's also a good question when you are making rounded nose cones for objecs such as rockets)

Comment: If you feel the need to say "please don't delete" - maybe you should have chosen a better title

Comment: Sounds like too broad. What exactly your problem consists in?

Comment: Sheesh people, I'm struggling to keep reputation up here! I'm also trying to make a rounded tip on a cone, and really have no idea how to do it except to bind a sphere to a cone and that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: and what's with Workflow?

Comment: related: (screw modifier) http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24506/using-the-screw-modifier-how-do-i-accurately-set-the-axis-of-rotation

Comment: possible duplicate (not question, but answer) http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28976/how-to-model-the-rounded-outline-of-a-column

Comment: oh my gosh guys, thank you so much for the overwhelming positive community response! If only I could see who upvoted things...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If a Screw Modifier isn't already enough, simple Polygon modelling will be surely.

- add a 5 (or more..) sided circle
- extrude up and scale to give hints of the shape
- then stick a subsurf modifier on it
- (optional) then use a *lattice* or a *curve modifier* for deformation. Deform to taste.

[image]

The lattice:

[image]

The Curve Modifier:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, that pretty much wraps up the question!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you went with a 5 sided circle?

Comment: For all things round I use 5 or more edges/verts for a profile, helps guide the subsurface modifier to produce truly round shapes. 5 is not entirely arbitrary, more could be used, but I like to let the subsurf modifier take care of that

Comment: The lattice isn't really needed for the prop

Comment: deform to taste, mushrooms are never perfect, a bit of "noise" or deformation can help give them character :)

Comment: Nowadays, I'd use 12 for the circle verticles; no latex nor curve (simply using proportional editing). Anyway, your suggestion is still valid and produces a good looking result. Chapeau.