# when i draw on my object, it only shows up on the net

Tags: modeling, materials

When I draw on my object, it only shows up on the net (not the object itself). When I draw on the net, it shows up on the drawing, but it isn't as user-friendly as it is drawing on the object itself. Yes, I have unwrapped the whole shape. [image: when drawing on the object, it would pop up on the net][image: when drawing on the net, it showed up on the object]

Comment: Hello and welcome, Please add screenshots of the issue to have a visial representation for the users to help you.

Comment: @Emir , thank you for responding! I have added pictures.

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image (Edit > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file (copy paste the link it will give you)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots the object is a bit plain, as I just started using blender. Here is the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/5ec29acb396041d0960a54067321d3b9 
I'm trying to make it a mushroom.

Comment: Hi and welcome. You can get a cleaner, less dense UV map if you model a low-poly mushroom, add a seam, and then unwrap it. Add modifiers to form and smooth the shape. Related question: [How to Model a Mushroom shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32345/107598)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it shows up on the other side of your object, it's because your normals are flipped, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*