# Change Object Relative Position to Origin

Tags: unity

Example:

I create a cube and change it's position to 0, 8, 0.

How do I make this new position its new origin?

I want to export it to Unity and manipulate the position, which is rendered very difficult because of the blender settings.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of changing an object's origin to a specific place.

- Place the 3D cursor where you want the origin of the object to be.  This can be done by either modifying it's position directly under the *3D Cursor* roliout of the <kbd>N</kbd> toolbar in the 3D view, or by selecting something and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *3D Cursor to Selected*.   Then select the object and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor*.
- You can set an object's origin to the world origin by applying its location with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Location*.

Answer (score 0):

just select you object go in object mode and click on origin to geometry like shown in the picture below.I think this is what you meant correct me if i am wrong.

[image]