# How to set my widget to bottom face my object or any face that ı wanted?

Tags: snapping

[image]

İn edit mode: shift + S 
in object mode: Ctrl + alt + shift + C not helping...

In 3dsmax for example there is a button which allows you can play with your widget without interferes with your object. so in short ı wanna do the thing same in the picture

Thanks people. ı appreciated. Its solved.

Comment: in edit mode, if you select the face, the transform widget _should_ go there...

Comment: İf ı do that in edit mode and lets say ı go back to object mode my widget will back to middle place of the object so..

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1291/19287

Comment: @Anesu ok, now I got it. in object mode, the transform manipulator is where the object "origin" is (usually in the object center). So, in edit mode, select the face then press SHIFT-S and select "cursor to selected". Then in object mode, in the toolbar "tools" tab choose "set origin" (or press "SHIFT-ALT_CTRL-C") option > "origin to 3d cursor". Done.