# How to keep origin point/cursor on object

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-cursor

I have noticed recently when moving new objects around, it doesn't keep the origin point/cursor on the object. See below - when I move the object, they do not move with the object, which affects the way it rotates, scales etc

Is there any way to set it so that it all moves in one?

[image]

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: You are not "moving objects" you are moving meshes in *Edit Mode*. Switch to *Object Mode*

Comment: When you move a mesh in edit mode, the origin remains in the same place. To re position the origin read this link: [Change pivot or local origin of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to get an understanding of objects in Blender. Your example shows an object in blender and the origin of that object is the large orange dot. When you move the object, the origin will move with it.

Now your object contains mesh information too. When you move your object, the mesh information moves too. However you CAN edit the mesh information by hitting the tab key to go into edit mode. While in edit mode, you can manipulate the mesh data belonging to the object, BUT NOT THE ORIGIN. This is what you are seeing in your example; you are in edit mode moving the mesh, but not the object.

If you wish to move the object, get out of edit mode by clicking the tab key again, then move your object.

It's also unclear by your question if you understand the difference between the cursor and an object origin. For information on the cursor see [Blender 3D Cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html?highlight=cursor)

Answer (score 3):

this one for blender 2.8 and above
Apart from the answer I found on this forum, this one worked for me.
I was facing this problem where pivot was offset to object
[image: I was facing this problem where pivot was offset to object]

In this you press F3 and type set origin
this will appear[image: set origin]

Then I just selected geometry to origin [image: geometry to origin]
and the problem was solved,
pivot moved to the center of object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the answers above did not help.

Select the "Bounding Box Centre" option from the "Transform Pivot Point" drop down as shown

[image]

Comment: The screenshots in the question clearly show that the author is in _Edit Mode_, in this case moving the mesh will not move the origin. Selecting _Bounding Box Center_ will not change this fact. This might work as a _Pivot Point_ in _Edit Mode_ (but then it's not much different from the default _Median Point_ in most cases), but if you go back into _Object Mode_ both _Bounding Box_ and _Median Point_ will scale and rotate around the origin point of the object. And if you've moved the mesh this might be way off the center of the geometry.