# Snap object to the center of another object face

Tags: snapping

Hi I got a Cube and a Cylinder. What is the fastest way (minimal steps) to move the Cylinder, so the center of the bottom face of the Cylinder will snap to the center of top face of the Cube ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Three Steps

1. [Make **origin**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object) of **Cylinder** at it's bottom face.
2. [Place **3D Cursor**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) on the top face of the **Cube**.
3. Move **Cylinder** (*Selection*) to **3D Cursor**.

[image: steps]

Answer (score 2):

**2 1/2 Steps**

In Object Mode, With *Pivot* set to 'Active Element', *Manipulate Center Points* switched On, *Snap* Off, but set to 'Face' and 'Closest'..

- Select Cylinder, then Cube, and <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>
- *If* the bottom of the cylinder isn't close to the top of the cube, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> until it is.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to snap the bottom of Cylinder to the top of Cube.

Comment: But there are so many settings I'd have to undo again, in real life I'd do it @cgslav 's way.