# Setting origin of empty "group" object

Tags: origin

I have an object that consists of 2 meshes.
To group them, I have added an Empty object and added my 2 objects as children.

I have then put the 3D cursor where I would the origin of the grouped object like to be.

Then I click "Origin to 3D Cursor", but nothing happens. The orange dot stays where it is. I expected it to go where the 3D cursor is.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set the origin for empties. They're just little more than an origin and a world matrix.

**For Blender 2.82 and later:**

In the header of the 3D View there is a drop down labelled *Options*. Within you can choose that the transform shall only affect the *Parents*. Select the empty, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and click *Selection to Cursor* to move it to the cursor's location. The location of the children will not be modified.

[image: Affect only]

Note that the "affect only" option already exists since Blender 2.81, but the *Snap* transform didn't support it before commit [3ba5461af0c8b1273d3daf87d050c24a690273be](https://developer.blender.org/rB3ba5461af0c8b1273d3daf87d050c24a690273be).

**For Blender prior to 2.82:**

If you want to have the empty at the 3D cursor's location, you will have to position the empty there. It is necessary to remove the parent relationship first <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and add it back afterwards <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> if you don't want the parented objects to move with the empty. With the empty selected, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and click *Selection to Cursor* to move it to the cursor's location.

Comment: Is there a workaround with a large number of empties? I have a CAD import (Navisworks Simulate -> FBX -> blender) with all objects at origin, including three-four levels of empties representing a hierarchy.

Comment: @ÅsmundHj Depends on what you mean by a workaround. What do you want to do with the empties? There is now an [option to only affect the parents](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157558/74827), allowing to move the empty without removing the parent-child relationship first. Perhaps it's better if you post a new question for this.

Comment: I would like to set the origin of all parents to be the a function (average?) of the origins of the children, which I think is the original question. I just have too many of them to do it manually.

Comment: @ÅsmundHj Please post this as a new question and add an example screenshot showing the hierarchy. I'll take a look.

Comment: I ended up doing 
```
def update_origins_from_children(obj):
    if obj.type=='EMPTY':
        barn = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, [update_origins_from_children(o) for o in obj.children]))        
        antall = len(barn)
        if antall>0:
            print(barn[0:4])
            total = sum(barn, Vector((0.0,0.0,0.0)) )
            nypos = total/antall
            for barn in obj.children:
                barn.location-=nypos
            obj.location=nypos
            return nypos
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return obj.location
```

Answer (score 0):

The following python function goes through all empties and moves them based on children origins. (Set mesh origins using Select Hierarchy and Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry first)

```
def update_origins_from_children(obj):
    if obj.type=='EMPTY':
        barn = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, [update_origins_from_children(o) for o in obj.children]))        
        antall = len(barn)
        if antall>0:
            print(barn[0:4])
            total = sum(barn, Vector((0.0,0.0,0.0)) )
            nypos = total/antall
            for barn in obj.children:
                barn.location-=nypos
            obj.location=nypos
            return nypos
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return obj.location
```