# 3d chess pieces from bezier curves

Tags: bezier-curves, splines

I am trying to make a chess set in Blender

I have made chess pieces blueprints as 2d bezier curves in Adobe Illustrator. Now I would like to import them to Blender and then using Lathe-like operation create 3d shapes from them.

It appars that if I export/import SVG files, there's tonnes of problems, like wrong pivot point etc.

Is there a quick and easy way to make what I intend to do?
Thank you

Comment: SVG file is a common way to import. Pivoting point can be changed. What are the other problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this on changing the origin of the imported SVG curves: [Change pivot or local origin of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object)

I imported the SVG from Illustrator, changed the origin point and added a screw modifier. One thing to note, my imported SVG curve was a closed shape. I deleted a curve segment on the axis I wanted to spin around by selecting the two curve point that made the segment, right-clicked and chose "delete segment".

Here's a file you can see an example.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What if the combinatio "Ctrl+Alt+Shift + C " which is commonly used in pivot change is doing nothing at all? Nothing happens when I hold those buttons

Comment: ok, never mind, I have found the panel without shortcuts.