# Layout object placement

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

A noob question: I scaled the default cube to 8m along x. If I set transform to 4m (in x), why isn't the object now just sitting on the ground plane? Isn't the origin of the object in the center by default?

Comment: The object origin is set in the center of the cube (x/2, y/2,z/2) by default. If you want to have it at the center of your ground plane, you have to [set it manually](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1291/23985).

Comment: Thanks for your response, which makes perfect sense. I'm not really trying to move the origin, I'm just trying to understand why using transform to move the object isn't acting as I expect. Like I mentioned, I scaled it to 8m tall, so 4m should be the origin in x, but when I use the transform to move it to 4m in x, the whole cube should be sitting on the ground plane, but it is not. I have to set the x location to 8m for it to sit on the ground plane.

Answer (score 0):

To make it sit on the ground plane you need to move it in the Z axis. If your cube is 1m in height then setting 0.5 in Z will make it sit on the ground plane.

Comment: Thanks for your response, which makes perfect sense. I'm not really trying to move the origin, I'm just trying to understand why using transform to move the object isn't acting as I expect. Like I mentioned, I scaled it to 8m tall, so 4m should be the origin in x, but when I use the transform to move it to 4m in x, the whole cube should be sitting on the ground plane, but it is not. I have to set the x location to 8m for it to sit on the ground plane.