# How to make the trees on the grid not through the grid? (Speedtrees, origin problem)

Tags: particles, hair

The trees and the grid are joined somehow and I don't know how to undo this.
This is the tutorial I'm following [Large Scale Forest Flyover in Blender 2.8 - Quick and Dirty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ky9Tfn31dDo&t=90s)

1:30 is what applies to me the trees appear halfway through the plane and I don't know how to fix this. I want the trees on the plane NOT halfway through.

[image: transparent tree image]

Comment: you need to move it up in Edit mode (not Object mode) so that it shifts from its origin

Comment: Please don't ask a question that is solely about the presence of an external video that can go offline at any time. Briefly describe what's going on, what you did, where the problem is. Also, a screenshot helps readers to quickly understand if they can answer the question or if this question is possibly relevant to a similar problem.

Comment: The answer to your question follows in the video right from 1.30 to 1:37.

Answer (score 0):

The orange dot in the center is the object's origin (the root of your tree). To move it down to the Z=0 position (the ground), switch to *Edit* mode and move all vertices of the mesh up.
[image: animation from the video]

Another option is to [use the 3D cursor (and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> menu)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1292/107598), or [move the origin directly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157558/107598) in *Object* mode.