# How to place 3D-cursor through a transparant object?

Tags: 3d-cursor

I want to place the 3D-cursor on the face of an object (object A), so I can import an extra object at that specific place. To know where to place the cursor I use a transparent object above object A. If I now place the cursor this cursor is placed on the transparent object. Does anyone know how I can place the cursor on object A, so through the transparent object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change pivot or local origin of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place the 3D-cursor on the face of an object, select the object and in edit mode select only that face. Then use the snapping menu to snap the 3d cursor to *selected object*.  You don't need the transparent object.

Comment: The transparent object is needed because it indicates the exact position where the cursor should be placed on the object below it.